# How does User.Claims are added from JWT (access token) in .net core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, claims

this might sound like a strange question but there is some kind of flow in our code that I can't figure out what is going on and need some help from the .net community

in our startup.cs we have the following code that adds the authentication:

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer()
        .AddCookie("Cookie");
}
```

When someone is calling the service (using rest API call) he must provide a valid AccessToken in the Authorization header.

Now, we have a Filter class that is checking that when accessing a given  method in a controller the user has the correct claim this method needs

this is the filter class:

```
namespace Authorization
{
    public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly Claim _claim;

        public ClaimRequirementFilter(Claim claim)
        {
            _claim = claim;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {

            var hasClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(c =>
                                    string.Equals(c.Type, _claim.Type, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                    && string.Equals(c.Value, _claim.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (!hasClaim)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the way we are using it is like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetUsers")]
[ClaimRequirement("api_access", "users.read")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
{
    return Ok("Great success!");
}
```

Now, what I can't figure out is how HttpContext.User.Claims is getting the claims from the JWT token ?
I read so many documentation and articles but I can't figure this out

if someone has any shred of data this would be a great help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging the answer was that the AddJwtBearer function performs authentication by extracting and validating a JWT token from the Authorization request header.

So the User.Claims are being populated after a valid JWT validation from the Authorization header

More info can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Check this introduction to JWT tokens here:
https://jwt.io/introduction

The claims are extracted from the "payload" section of the token by decoding it. This is done with a library built into the .NET Core Framework so you are not seeing the details. It is being taken care of for you.

Usually, JWT tokens are Base64Url encoded.

If you want to get a better idea of what is actually in your JWT token and decode it manually, use this decoder:

https://jwt.io/

Copy and paste your authorization token there and you should see it decoded. You can see the header, payload and signature decoded separately.